# VMWare horizon client invisible mouse pointer

Tags: mouse, vmware

- Host:  Windows Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763
- VM: Windows 10
- VMWare Horizon Client:  5.0.0 build-12606690

I attempted the fixes for [VMWare Invisible Mouse Pointer](https://superuser.com/questions/375426/vmware-invisible-mouse-pointer), but they did not work.  I figured this might be a different application than what they are referring to so I created this question instead.

Comment: What version of the VMWare Tools do you have installed?  What is the last cumulative update you installed?

Comment: Horizon Client is the VMWare tool.  We decided to give me a new VM because we deduced that it was a driver issue on the actual VM itself.  Very odd issue, but I guess it happens.

Comment: Horizon View client when installed installs the VMware tools.  I know this because I have a Horizon deployment at work I manage

Comment: Oh ok, umm well I checked the about screen and also the installed apps on Windows, but I don't see VMWare tools anywhere, so do you know how I would give you the version info for VMWare tools?

Comment: We ended up just bombing my virtual machine and starting with a fresh virtual machine.  The Admins were commenting that it seemed to be the driver that was messed up.  I def did NOT mess with any drivers lol.  So it all ended up fine.  Was super annoying issue though.

Answer (score 1):

Was experiencing same upgrading client to latest version solved it for me - https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/53152

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Turns out, somehow my mouse drivers got corrupted on my VDI, they had to give me a brand new VDI.  Obviously I wasn't touching those drivers so I guess computer fluke.